# How to call a function within a nested class?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I have the following nested class:

```
class Classifiers(object):

    class RF():
        @staticmethod
        def classifier():
            print "RF CLASF"
            return

    class KN():
        def create_model(self):
            print "This is KN Model"
            return

        @staticmethod
        def classifier():
            arg = self.create_model()
```

The first class `RF` I can execute sucessfully using:

```
rf = Classifiers.RF()
rf_clsf = rf.classifier()
# prints RF CLASF
```

But when I call the second class `KN` the following way:

```
kn = Classifiers.KN()
kn_clsf = kn.classifier()
```

I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  NameError
  <ipython-input-32-5d9ba3c7c927> in <module>()
  ----> 1 kn_clsf = kn.classifier()

  <ipython-input-28-6147200d928b> in classifier()
       15         @staticmethod
       16         def classifier():
  ---> 17             arg = self.create_model()

  NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

I expected it to print "This is KN Model".
What's the right way to do it?

Comment: ... *what* error? Also, is there a particular reason you're nesting classes.

Comment: `self` is not defined in `@staticmethod`, because the method is static.

Comment: Why are you using nested classes? Python doesn't have a privacy model, so you don't need to nest classes to 'share' access either. They are *just attributes* on the parent class.

Comment: Also, why are you then using `staticmethod`s? You now just have functions, they may as well just live in a module. If you are trying to produce a nested namespace, you are better off using packages and modules. At that point `create_model` is just another global in the `Classifiers.KN` module.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen with static methods. Why did you make it static? Without more context, *"what's the right way"* to do what?

Comment: Anyway, if you want to have access to the class a method is defined on, use a `@classmethod`, not `@staticmethod`. Note that Python `staticmethod` is not the same thing a `static` in other languages.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: can you give example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the method a static function; this removes all context from a function (it remains unbound).

You could make the method a *`classmethod`* instead, so it is bound to the class:

```
class KN():
    @staticmethod
    def create_model():
        return "This is KN Model"

    @classmethod
    def classifier(cls):
        arg = cls.create_model()
```

I made `create_model` a static function there, and have it *return* the string value rather than use `print`.

Or, since you are creating instances, you may as well make these regular methods:

```
class KN():
    def create_model(self):
        return "This is KN Model"

    def classifier(self):
        arg = self.create_model()
```

However, I'm concerned that you are approaching Python coming from Java or C# here. If so, then do know that the term `static` has a *different meaning* in Python; you are not defining per-class data and methods here.  You'd generally use class attributes and class methods where in other languages you'd make things `static`.

Nor does Python have a privacy model, which necessitates nested classes to be able to share access to the inner workings of the parent class. If you wanted to create a nested namespace, in Python you commonly would use *modules* instead, at which point `Classifiers` would be a package, and `KN` and `RF` each a module containing plain functions (so `create_model` would be another global that `classifier` would call).

Comment: @MartinPieters: how do you invoke it?

Comment: @neversaint: invoke what?

Comment: Invoke classifier. Like `kn = Classifiers.KN()` then `kn_clsf = kn.classifier()`?

Comment: @neversaint: yes, or `Classifiers.KN.classifier()`. Since all your methods are static or class methods, you don't actually need any instances, do you.

Comment: @neversaint: note that you never explained *why* you are using nested classes or think you need static methods. I can only speculate here why you think you need this.

Comment: I have many classifiers which I put under the hood `class Classifier()`

Comment: @MartinPieters: I tried your code it still give error. Can you give the full code with invocation so that it can print "This is KN Model"

Comment: @neversaint you probably want a `classifiers` module, not a `Classifier` class. If you do want the class, it should probably be a superclass, perhaps abstract, defining the interface. However, again, this is tricky without context.

Comment: @neversaint: but are you ever creating an instance of the `Classifier()` class, or are you just grouping the classifiers? Then use a module, named `classifiers`, and put your classes is there.

Comment: @neversaint: I can't see your error, and I can run this code without issues. It is not clear to me why you'd want to use `print`, then `return`; that just returns `None`, which is almost certainly the wrong value to store in `arg`. All we can do is solve your immediate issue that you shared in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You used `@staticmethod` for classifier. This way, You're telling Python that this function can be called from KN instance, but that function itself is unaware of other functions inside KN class.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confused with the meaning of "static".

A static member is a member shared by all the instances of the class. So, when you decorate a method with `@staticmethod`, this method becomes shared by all the instances of your class. Hence, creating a `kn` object and then calling `kn.classifier()` does not actually make sense, since `classifier` is not intended to act on a particular instance of `KN`.

More technically, Python bugs because you are referring to something called `self` in your `KN.classifier` method, but you did not tell him what `self` is.
In contrast, a instance method has `self` as first argument, so Python knows what `self` refers to.

Concerning why your call to `rf.classifier()` works, my guess is that static methods do not actually exist in Python (you declare them with decorators, but decorators did not exist in the first place). Hence, writing `rf.classifier` performs a call to the method `classifier` from the `RF` class.So you are calling the `classifier` method, which does exist, and which can actually run since no reference to `self` is made.